# Move/Copy node to multiple child nodes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I'm completely new to XSLT and need some help to solve one of my issues. What I want to accomplish is this:

I have a file looking something like this:

```
<Transaction>
    <Date>2010-10-14T12:06:12.164+01:00</Date>
    <Production>NO</Production>
    <Document fun:OID="1.9.101106">
        <DocumentType xmlns="">Monthly A</DocumentType>
        <RangeName xmlns="">Range Name</RangeName>
        <Name xmlns="">Equity</Name>
        <Language xmlns="">English</Language>
        <Class xmlns="">A Acc</Class>
        <Active xmlns="">YES</Active>
        <Country xmlns="">UK</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Luxembourg</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Denmark</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Malta</Country>
        <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101106" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
              <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc-FMR-UKEN</Name>
              <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
              <FileType>pdf</FileType>
              <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
              <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
        </Primary>
        <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101118" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
              <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc</Name>
              <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
              <FileType>pdf</FileType>
              <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
              <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
        </Primary>
    </Document>
</Transaction>
```

And I want to keep the current file, except that I want to copy the country nodes in to be in the Primary node. So it would look something like this:

```
<Transaction>
    <Date>2010-10-14T12:06:12.164+01:00</Date>
    <Production>NO</Production>
    <Document fun:OID="1.9.101106">
        <DocumentType xmlns="">Monthly A</DocumentType>
        <RangeName xmlns="">Range Name</RangeName>
        <Name xmlns="">Equity</Name>
        <Language xmlns="">English</Language>
        <Class xmlns="">A Acc</Class>
        <Active xmlns="">YES</Active>
        <Country xmlns="">UK</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Luxembourg</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Denmark</Country>
        <Country xmlns="">Malta</Country>
        <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101106" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
              <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc-FMR-UKEN</Name>
              <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
              <FileType>pdf</FileType>
              <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
              <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
              <Country xmlns="">UK</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Luxembourg</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Denmark</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Malta</Country>
        </Primary>
        <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101118" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
              <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc</Name>
              <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
              <FileType>pdf</FileType>
              <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
              <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
              <Country xmlns="">UK</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Luxembourg</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Denmark</Country>
              <Country xmlns="">Malta</Country>
        </Primary>
    </Document>
</Transaction>
```

What would the best approach be to accomplish that? Do I need to do a copy of the whole document first and then copy the individual countries, or can I do this in one go somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use an [identity template](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity) to copy the whole document but still be able to modify the parts you want:

**With this (slightly modified) input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
  <Date>2010-10-14T12:06:12.164+01:00</Date>
  <Production>NO</Production>
  <Document fun1:OID="1.9.101106">
    <DocumentType xmlns="">Monthly A</DocumentType>
    <RangeName xmlns="">Range Name</RangeName>
    <Name xmlns="">Equity</Name>
    <Language xmlns="">English</Language>
    <Class xmlns="">A Acc</Class>
    <Active xmlns="">YES</Active>
    <Country xmlns="">UK</Country>
    <Country xmlns="">Luxembourg</Country>
    <Country xmlns="">Denmark</Country>
    <Country xmlns="">Malta</Country>
    <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101106" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
      <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc-FMR-UKEN</Name>
      <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
      <FileType>pdf</FileType>
      <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
      <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
    </Primary>
    <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101118" xmlns="" xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
      <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc</Name>
      <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
      <FileType>pdf</FileType>
      <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
      <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
    </Primary>
  </Document>
</Transaction>
```

---

**Explanation for the changes in input XML:** The supplied input XML isn't valid because you use double quotes for every attribute. Also, the `fun` prefix isn't declared for the `Document` node. I've changed the `fun` prefix to `fun1` and bound the prefix at root level.

---

**And this stylesheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- This identity template copies the document -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This template will only match the 'Primary' nodes
       and modify them the way you want. -->
  <xsl:template match="Primary">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
      <!-- As you can see, this is the only difference
           between the identity template and this specific
           template. -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="../Country"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will give you an identical document but with `Country` copied into `Primary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns:fun1="DocumentXML.com">
  <Date>2010-10-14T12:06:12.164+01:00</Date>
  <Production>NO</Production>
  <Document fun1:OID="1.9.101106">
      <DocumentType>Monthly A</DocumentType>
      <RangeName>Range Name</RangeName>
      <Name>Equity</Name>
      <Language>English</Language>
      <Class>A Acc</Class>
      <Active>YES</Active>
      <Country>UK</Country>
      <Country>Luxembourg</Country>
      <Country>Denmark</Country>
      <Country>Malta</Country>
      <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101106">
         <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc-FMR-UKEN</Name>
         <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
         <FileType>pdf</FileType>
         <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
         <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
         <Country>UK</Country>
         <Country>Luxembourg</Country>
         <Country>Denmark</Country>
         <Country>Malta</Country>
      </Primary>
      <Primary fun1:OID="1.9.101118">
         <Name>SISF-Indian-Equity-A-Acc</Name>
         <FileSizeInKB>176784</FileSizeInKB>
         <FileType>pdf</FileType>
         <ReportingPeriod>September</ReportingPeriod>
         <ReportingYear>2010</ReportingYear>
         <Country>UK</Country>
         <Country>Luxembourg</Country>
         <Country>Denmark</Country>
         <Country>Malta</Country>
      </Primary>
  </Document>
</Transaction>
```

Comment: Thanks for exceptional fast, good and detailed answer! Solved everything. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm sorry, but can only upvote your answer one time, would do it more if I could! :D

Comment: The reason for all the double qoutes was my fault because I was just copying from a test I have. There for I had them all excepted. However, I noticed one thing, that it won't copy attributes now when using this. And as far as I know and can understand it should, shouldn't it? Or can you specify in the copy that you don't want the attributes or that you do?

Comment: It does copy all attributes except the default namespace declaration `xmlns=""`. Since all it says is that the default namespace is not declared and since this is the default behavior the `xmlns=""` on every node is not needed. If you would declare the default namespace on `Transaction` to anything else but an empty string (eg. `xmlns="example.com"`), the transformation would automatically add the empty default namespace declaration to all descendants having an empty default namespace.

Comment: Cool, then I get it! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, the shortest stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::Primary/../Country"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Other shorter without changing the identity rule:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Primary/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Country"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Both don't use `xsl:copy-of` but `xsl:apply-templates`. This allows further processing.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out for fun as I already implemented @Per T 's version. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

well if you are using xslt to generate a new xml doccument i would just create the doccument then for the primary node do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="../Country">
<Country><xsl:value-of select="."/></Country>
</xsl:for-each>
```

there may be simpler ways to achieve the same results..?